# The identity map $\Delta^n \rightarrow \Delta^n$ is a basis for $H_n(\Delta^n, \delta\Delta^n; R)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, simplicial-stuff

> Show that the identity map $\Delta^n \rightarrow \Delta^n$ is a basis for $H_n(\Delta^n, \delta\Delta^n; R)$.

Here $\Delta^n$ is the n-simplex, and I know $\delta \Delta^n$ denotes its "boundary", but I'm not completely sure what that means--I think it's the set of all n-1-simplices contained in $\Delta^n$, but I'm not sure. Most importantly, I don't understand what it means for a map to be a basis for a homology group. I wrote down the following anyway:

> If n = 0, $\delta\Delta^0$ is empty and there is nothing to prove; if n = 1, $(\Delta^1, \delta\Delta^1)$ is a good pair and $\Delta^1/\delta\Delta^1$ is the circle $S^1$, and the identity map has only one element, which generates $\mathbb{Z}$. Otherwise, $H_n(\Delta^n; R) ≅ H_{n-1}(\Delta^n; R) ≅ 0$ since $\Delta^n$ is contractible, so the long exact sequence $... \rightarrow H_n(\delta\Delta^n; R)$ $\rightarrow H_n(\Delta^n; R)$ $\rightarrow H_n(\Delta^n, \delta\Delta^n; R)$ $\rightarrow H_{n-1}(\delta\Delta^n; R)$ $\rightarrow H_{n-1}(\Delta^n;R) \rightarrow ...$ has a section $0 \rightarrow H_n(\Delta^n, \delta\Delta^n; R)$ $\rightarrow H_{n-1}(\delta\Delta^n; R) \rightarrow 0$ and so $H_n(\Delta^n, \delta\Delta^n; R) ≅ H_{n-1}(\delta\Delta^n; R)$. The identity map takes each element of $\delta\Delta^n$ to itself, and $H_{n-1}(\delta\Delta^n)$ is generated by elements of $\delta\Delta^n$, so the result follows.

I am reasonably sure that this "proof" is **wrong**, probably for multiple reasons, but I don't really understand the question. I just tried to do what I know how to do to homology groups to come up with something that sounds vaguely related to the question. I want help understanding the question so I can make an actual answer to it, and I'm hoping what I wrote down will help clarify what I do and don't understand already about the question.

Comment: The identity map $i : \Delta^n \to \Delta^n$ is a special case of a singular $n$-simplex $\sigma :\Delta^n \to X$. From any singular $n$-simplex $\sigma$ you get a singular $n$-chain, by assigning coefficient $1$ to $\sigma$ and coefficient $0$ to every other singular simplex. So, to say that "$i$ is a basis for $H_n(\Delta^n,\delta\Delta^n;R)$" means that the singular chain defined by $i$ as above is cycle, and that the singular homology class of that cycle is a basis for $H_n(\Delta^n,\delta\Delta^n;R)$.

Comment: In my previous comment, where I wrote "cycle" you should read it as "relative cycle".

Comment: I'm having a hard time getting my head around this part of the theory. Does the identity map of $\Delta^n$ usually generate the nth group in the chain ($C_n$), or are multiple ways to map $\Delta^n$ onto itself, with some sane way to count them?

Comment: Let me ask, are you familiar with the concepts surrounding the definition of singular homology, as explained, say, in Hatcher's textbook? My first comment is written exactly in that language.

Comment: I've read the part of the section in Hatcher's book on the subject a few times, I'm just having trouble fully making sense of it.

Comment: The key thing you need here is that for any topological space $X$, its group of singular $n$-chains is the free abelian group generated by the **set** of continuous functions $\Delta^n \mapsto X$. This can be applied in a kind of self-referential way when $X=\Delta^n$, in which case the identity map is just one very special continuous function.

Comment: Probably you just have to wrap your mind around this a few more times, but it sounds like you have all the necessary pieces.